# as3/javascript loan formula to calculate principle from weekly rate

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, math

I have an AS3 function to calculate weekly repayment value provided I have values of loan amount, interest rate & term in years.

```
private function calculateRepayment(_loanAmount, _years, _interest):Number
{
    var nWeek = _years * 52;
    var nInterest = _interest/(52*100);
    var nRepayment = ( _loanAmount * nInterest *Math.pow((1+nInterest),nWeek) ) / ( Math.pow((1+nInterest),nWeek)-1 );
    return Number(nRepayment);
}
```

**Now I need to write a function to calculate loan amount from the values of weekly repayment, interest rate & term in years.**

Any help on the formula converted to AS3 or javascript would be great thanks, I think in theory it is loanAmount = interest/rate time.

Eg:

```
private function calculateLoanAmount(_repaymentAmount, _years, _interest):Number
{
    // var nLoanAmount:Number = ????
    return Number(nLoanAmount);
}
```

Comment: Its a flash loan calculator I am developing for a friend.

Comment: shoulden't it be: `var nRepayment = ( _loanAmount *Math.pow((1+nInterest),nWeek) ) / nWeek;`

that is, i'm not sure how this loan works,

Comment: when doing homework use this link http://tinyurl.com/l5fkktq

Comment: No pseudoDust that is incorrect it should be var nRepayment:Number = _loanAmount * nInterest / (1 - (Math.pow(1/(1 + nInterest), nTerm)));

Answer (score 0):

OK I worked it out, here is the function:

```
private function calculateLoanAmount(_repayment, _years, _interest):Number
{
    var p:Number = _repayment; // weekly payment
    var i:Number = (_interest / 52) * 0.01; // weekly interest factor
    var n:Number = _years * 52; // number of weekly payments - (5 years) 5*52 = 260
    var principal:Number = (p * (1 - 1 / (Math.pow(1 + i, n)))) / i;
    principal = Math.round(roundDec(principal, 0)); // prepare for output
    return Number(principal);
}
```